# Redefine class/model of python module

Tags: python, django, module

I want to use `django-achievements` ([link](https://github.com/ssaboum/django-achievements/tree/master/achievements)) module in my app, but it lack some fields in it's model. For example, I want to add `CharField` to it with path to picture of the badge/achievement. Also I will need to modify module's `engine.py` file for that.

What is the right way to do that? Download that module to my main app' folder and modify original files, or i can somehow redefine some methods/classes of original `models.py` and `engine.py` locally without modifing original files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say fork it and make your own modifications directly to the source. If it's an improvement  you can create a Pull Request and contribute your code to the actual repository (not required, you can always just keep it for your own use).